# CSV data import using Dataflow in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am importing data from csv (file in storage) to BigQuery using dataflow. I am creating dataflow using existing template "text Files on cloud storage to BigQuery". I am owner of GCP account but still I gave permission for different BigQuery roles as mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640105/bigquery-unable-to-insert-job-workflow-failed

I am getting error message as "Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create job with prefix beam_bq_job_LOAD_textiotobigquerydataflow0releaser01181655135f622d5e_fd7c58dd997c4778989618b7cc9232f7_f4de7979252441e28f37f4de908b70ba_00001_00000, reached max retries: 3, last failed job: null. org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJob.runJob(BigQueryHelpers.java:199) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJobManager.waitForDone(BigQueryHelpers.java:152) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.finishBundle(WriteTables.java:376)"

Can anyone please help me  on this.

Comment: Does the service account that the dataflow job is using have the correct permissions to access the Cloud Storage bucket and csv files?

Comment: Why do you use dataflow before ingesting in BigQuery? It's always faster and cheaper (and simpler), to load the whole CSV file in BigQuery and then to perform data cleaning with a SQL query. Do you have special constraint?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.